# Does commutativity extend to functions with 3+ arguments?

Tags: abstract-algebra

As far as I know, commutativity is a property of binary operators.

Does it apply to functions with 3+ arguments? If so, are all permutations considered, or just rotations, or what?

Comment: Whatever is useful.  Definitions do not come from nowhere.  The definition of "commutative" for an operation with two arguments describes a useful property, and that is why you learn about it in math class.  If some similar property is useful for what you want to do with functions of $3$ arguments, go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Considering a binary operation as a function of its two operands, one way to extend the idea of commutativity to more than two operands is to consider [symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function).
The value of a symmetric function applied to some list of parameters is the same as its value for any permutation of that list of parameters.

If an operation on $n$ operands is defined as a symmetric function of the operands,
then by definition its value does not change due to any permutation of the operands.

You could also consider a restricted set of permutations of the parameters. Your suggestion of allowing rotations could be interesting.

Another possibility is to consider an operation whose result is unchanged by any *even* permutation of its operands (that is, a permutation that can be implemented by an even number of transpositions; a transposition swaps the positions of two operands).

A special case of allowing even permutations of the parameters is an operation whose result is negated whenever you transpose two of its operands.